# How can I optimize updating Postgres using Delphi (BDE components)?

Tags: delphi, postgresql, query-optimization, delphi-7

I am working in Delphi 7 and PostgreSQL 9.0, and have fifty tables in my database. I have a situation where I have to execute more than fifty update queries at once, one for each table.

I have a procedure:

```
var
sTheQuery : string;
begin 
sTheQuery    :='update diary set remark = replace(remark,'+#39+'%'+#39+', '$')';
QueryImages.SQL.Clear;
QueryImages.SQL.Text:=sTheQuery;
QueryImages.ExecSQL;

sTheQuery    :='update bioschema set note = replace(note,'+#39+'%'+#39+', '$')';
QueryImages.SQL.Clear;
QueryImages.SQL.Text:=sTheQuery;
QueryImages.ExecSQL;
sTheQuery    :='update displaymaps set region = replace(region, '+#39+'%'+#39+', '$')';
QueryImages.SQL.Clear;
QueryImages.SQL.Text:=sTheQuery;
  QueryImages.ExecSQL;
sTheQuery    :='update ecosystem set description = replace(description,'+#39+'%'+#39+', '$')';
QueryImages.SQL.Clear;
QueryImages.SQL.Text:=sTheQuery;
  QueryImages.ExecSQL;

.
.
// total 50 times
end;
```

Is this approach an improvement?:

```
    var
    sTheQuery   : string;
    begin
    sTheQuery    :='update diary set remark = replace(remark,'+#39+'%'+#39+', '$');';
    sTheQuery    :=sTheQuery+'update bioschema set note = replace(note,'+#39+'%'+#39+', '$');';
    sTheQuery    :=sTheQuery+'update displaymaps set region = replace(region, '+#39+'%'+#39+', '$');';
    sTheQuery    :=sTheQuery+'update ecosystem set description = replace(description, '+#39+'%'+#39+', '$');';
    .
    .//total 50 times
    .
    QueryImages.SQL.Clear;
    QueryImages.SQL.Text:=sTheQuery;
     QueryImages.ExecSQL;
    end.
```

Comment: Im using BDE components to fire the queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend neither. I would refactor my code to create a method that accepts the query and processes it, like this pseudo code:

```
executeQuery(String sTheQuery) {
   QueryImages.SQL.Clear;
   QueryImages.SQL.Text:=sTheQuery;
   QueryImages.ExecSQL;
}

doit() {
    executeQuery('update diary set remark = replace(remark,'+#39+'%'+#39+', '$')');
    executeQuery('update bioschema set note = replace(note,'+#39+'%'+#39+', '$')');
    executeQuery('update displaymaps set region = replace(region, '+#39+'%'+#39+', '$')');
    executeQuery('update ecosystem set description = replace(description, '+#39+'%'+#39+', '$')');
}
```

This is maintainable, easy to read and understand, and it will perform acceptably.

Comment: yes thats nice maintainable, easy to read and understand piece of code

Comment: y cant i put the '@Bohemian' it just disapears

Comment: Yes - That sometimes happens for me too - the `@name` disappears. I haven't figured out a pattern when it does and doesn't

Comment: It happens when there's nobody else to address. The author of the answer and the author of the question are *automatically* notified of new comments, so there's no reason to address them specially with the "@" command. [That changed in July.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97098/33732)